# How to reset user control by getting the value from other form

Tags: c#, java, asp.net, winforms, button

I have form1 : User control and form2: form. I want to reset all the the value from form2 that will effect/reset showing to user control by using reset button. the user control get value from form2

something I tried:

```
RoomPlan.RoomStatus STATUS = rpRoomPlan[i].roomstatus();

if (STATUS == RoomPlan.RoomStatus.CLEAN) 
{ 
    generateRoomPlan(); 
    om.IM_RESET_ROOM_STATUS(Convert.ToInt32(ROOMID)); 
    rpRoomPlan[i].Enabled = true; 
    rpRoomPlan[i].BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke; 
}
```

om.IM_RESET_ROOM_STATUS is the web service *

```
  case RoomStatus.CLEAN:
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dr["ROOMID"].ToString())){
  updateRoomDisplay(Color.DeepSkyBlue, Color.DeepSkyBlue, Color.LimeGreen,
                                        "BOOK", "ASSIGNED", "", Color.White, Color.WhiteSmoke, Color.WhiteSmoke, "", "", true);}
```

*when we click the reset button then the status BOOK ASSIGNED will change to BOOK UNASSIGN

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! What did you try already?(maybe show us some code)

Comment: add button reset to user control..and add some coding into reset button.. RoomPlan.RoomStatus STATUS = rpRoomPlan[i].roomstatus();
                    
                    if (STATUS == RoomPlan.RoomStatus.CLEAN)
                    {
                        generateRoomPlan();
                        
                        om.IM_RESET_ROOM_STATUS(Convert.ToInt32(ROOMID));
                       
                        rpRoomPlan[i].Enabled = true;
                        rpRoomPlan[i].BackColor = Color.WhiteSmoke;
                    }

Comment: om.IM_RESET_ROOM_STATUS is the web service

Comment: You can edit your question with the edit button underneath it. I edited so the code is in there.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the form by simply calling it's designer's `InitializeComponent()` method. It's private by default, so create another public one:

```
public void ResetForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();
}
```

and then call it

```
form2.ResetForm();
```

Comment: where to put form2.ResetForm();

Comment: @user3354809 in the click event handler of the reset button

Comment: unfortunately cannot...because when user click the button reset then the form 2 will change to default value. currently the form 2 is already change and i want to reset it

Comment: what is the difference between 'change to default value' and the 'reset'?

Comment: actually form 2 is in user control..currently the form2 the status is 'book,assigned', then i want to reset it to default mean 'book,unassign'..but need tho edit the query also.. the status book,unassign is from form2...all the status is from form2..so want to reset it..